# How do I make a plane have thickness?

Tags: modeling

So I made this structure by subdividing a plane and elevating parts to make hallways:

[image]

Then I realized that I wanted to make the walls have a certain thickness.  Is there a way to do this?  Extruding didn't really work for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Solidify Modifier

You can do this by adding a *Solidify* modifier to your planes:

[image]